# dos command or batch file to get the path for the current active folder opened on my screen

Tags: batch-file, path, dos

Hi I saw this question [How can I get the current active window at the time a batch script is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722252/how-can-i-get-the-current-active-window-at-the-time-a-batch-script-is-run)

but didnt quite get what i wanted. They have given jscript and powershell script answers...so cant we get the path of the active window opened on the screen using dos commands.

Please help.

have tried - %cd% :: but it gives the path where the batch file is located not the folder that is currently opened and active on the desktop

Comment: Sorry--no, there is no way to do that with pure batch.

Comment: `%CD%` gives the current working directory. That _can_ be where the batch file is located. But, it can also be elsewhere. For instance, when the mybatch.bat file is executed using: `c:\>c:\bin\mybatch.bat` - calling `%CD%` from within mybatch.bat will output `c:\ `..

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    outp.writeline window.locationname
Next
```

to use

```
cscript /nologo c:\pathtoscript\script.vbs
```

Note it does Explorer and Internet Explorer windows for historical reasons - they used to be the same program.

Which gives output like this

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\David Candy>cscript /nologo "C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Assorted\Sc
ripts\ListOpenShellWindowsStdOut.vbs"
Newest 'batch-file' Questions - Stack Overflow
dos command or batch file to get the path for the current active folder opened o
n my screen - Stack Overflow
Music
Favorites
```

To get into a batch variable use a for loop

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript // nologo script.vbs') do Echo %%A
```